# Video editing and production questions

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic, scope

I would assume by the name of this site that video editing questions are off-topic, but I couldn't find anything discussed in the comments or sample questions of the proposal on Area 51.  Whether they're on- or off-topic I think it would be good to have the discussion and decision documented here on meta.

I'm specifically thinking of questions related to video editing in DAWs like Pro Tools that can do both audio and video editing.

Comment: @TomWij: Your comment is a perfectly acceptable answer. You should post it as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: We are now lauching a [SE filmmaking site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/47970/filmmaking/49657#49657) which might suit questions as those you've described

Answer (score 3):

I think experts in "Audio Recording and Production" won't be able to answer expert questions on "Video Recording and Production", an interaction between both would be discuss-able. But questions about pure video would be better answered by a site specialized in that, perhaps someone could propose it on Area 51?

Comment: My thoughts exactly.

Answer (score 2):

While audio and video are going hand in hand very often, you might expect questions about syncing stuff, SMPTE and other timecode-related stuff as well as - as mentioned - questions about DAWs and video linking.

While these questions are in my opinion very genuine and applicable to our subject, we should always be alerted that we are not going too much off topic with it. As soon as people are discussing "what effect to use in my video when the audio does *bleep*" or so, I think we are getting off topic.

Looking at the structure of StackExchange (i.e. new question, new topic, things never get out of hand because there is no chronologically threaded stuff like in a forum, nobody answers on answers on answers) I think it is perfectly manageable, and therefore vote for the allowance of ***A/V related*** questions.

Comment: I agree with this.